# Cumulocity JSON via MQTT / measurement and error topic

Tags: json, mqtt, payload, cumulocity

I'm trying to send measurement values to my Cumulocity Tenant via JSON MQTT.
For my test connection I use MQTTBox.

I have already successfully sent data / create new deivces via MQTT.

```
100,MQTT-Simulation-1,c8y_MQTTdevice
211,80
```

I have now tried to change my format to JSON MQTT.
According to the Cumulocity IoT Guide (http://www.cumulocity.com/guides/mqtt/json/) I have defined my MQTT topic endpoint.

```
<api>/<resource>/<action>/<id>
measurement/measurements/create/231
```

- Topic to publish: measurement/measurements/create/231
- Payload Type: String / JSON / XML / Characters
- Payload: {"c8y_Temperature": {"T": {"unit": "°C","value": 35.742410434759904}}}

As described in the guide, the payload of SmartRest can be used?
The examples in the Guide looks different as described, no ID can be found here in the topic to publish.

A subscription to the topic **error** is also not possible. Only to the topic smartrest error **s/e**.

Answer (score 0):

JSON via MQTT will only be possible in the next release for my main tenant - cumulocity support.